# Upside down rotation doesn't trigger configuration change

Tags: android

When I turn my Android phone upside down, my Activity does not rotate to show the layout upside down but stays in landscape mode instead.  I tried this with a very simple HelloWorld app.  I added `android:configChanges="orientation"` to the manifest and overrode `onConfigurationChange()` in the Activity to set breakpoints there.  Rotating the device upside down produces one config change to go from portrait (upside up) to landscape but no second change from landscape to portrait (upside down).  Is this an Android issue or is there something I need to do?

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hello.world"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:name=".HelloWorldActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Activity:

```
public class HelloWorldActivity
  extends Activity
{
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }

  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
  {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
      Log.e("MDO", "orientation change: landscape");
    }
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
      Log.e("MDO", "orientation change: portrait");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your device does this?  I rarely see apps that allow this.

Comment: I haven't seen this behavior with a few standard apps (Settings, browser, etc) that I tried either but it is possible with `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not an issue, it's how Android works. It views upside-down only in landscape mode and not in portrait (and in landscape from version 2.2 if I remember correctly). Configuration change occurs when it goes from portrait to landscape and vice versa. If you want to check if the phone was flipped upside down or in whatever direction you'll have to access accelerometer sensor. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-quick-tutorial-on-coding-androids-accelerometer/472) on how to use it and here you have [`SensorManager` docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html).

EDIT: as the author of the question found out himself, adding `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"` to your manifest is enough, **provided that you don't want to support anything older than Android 2.3 (API level 9)**.

Comment: Do you have a link to Android doc that describes this?

Comment: Actually, if I add android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" I do get the desired behavior.

Comment: The problem is, it won't run on Androids older than 2.3 (API level 9). Or am I wrong? Did you test it?

Comment: My app requires 2.3 as a minimum so that restriction is not a problem.

Comment: Great. I'm glad you found the solution:)

Comment: This worked for me, but based on the documentation for the activity manifest element (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#screen), it looks like "fullUser" is a better choice because that respects the user's orientation lock setting.

Answer (score 4):

Setting `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"` accomplishes what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Include `screenSize` in your `configChanges` in your manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html:

> Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size" also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation" value. That is, you must decalare android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize". However, if your application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or higher device).